# Sort NSSortDescriptor by Month of date. Swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, core-data, swiftui

I'm displaying a list of birthdays. <s>I want to sort them in a way that starts with January and Ends with December and the second NSSortDescriptor being day.</s> I want to display a list with the closest birthdays appearing first.

Currently it sorts by the full birthday date. So currently "February 6 2009" displays after "February 8 1997" which I don't want it to be as year is irrelevant when wanting to know when the next birthday comes up.

What my FetchRequest looks like:

```
    @FetchRequest(entity: Birthday.entity(), sortDescriptors: [
    NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Birthday.date, ascending: true),

]) var birthdays: FetchedResults<Birthday>
```

What my List looks like:

```
                List {
                ForEach(birthdays, id: \.self) { birthday in
                    ZStack {
                        NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(birthday: birthday)) {
                            EmptyView()

                        }.hidden()

                        BirthdayView(name: birthday.name ?? "Unknown Name", birthDate: birthday.date ?? Date())

                    }
                }
                .onDelete(perform: deleteBirthdays)
            }
```

Im using Core Data and this is how my entity looks like:

[image]

Using latest XCODE and Swift.

Thanks in advance!

I tried:

```
extension Date {
var isInToday: Bool { Calendar.current.isDateInToday(self) }
var nextBirthday: Date {
    isInToday ? self : Calendar.current.nextDate(after: Date(), matching: Calendar.current.dateComponents([.month, .day, .hour, .minute], from: self), matchingPolicy: .nextTime)!
}
```

}

```
extension Birthday {
var nextBirthday: Date { date!.nextBirthday }
```

}

```
@FetchRequest(entity: Birthday.entity(), sortDescriptors: [
NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Birthday.nextBirthday, ascending: true)
]) var birthdays: FetchedResults<Birthday>
```

But when running the app it throws this shows the following error:

"Thread 1: Fatal error: Could not extract a String from KeyPath Swift.KeyPath"

Comment: Thanks I tried this but it now gives this error: "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom sort to get your dates sorted by incoming birthday and pass your collection sorted to your ForEach method:

```
extension Collection where Element == Birthday {
    func sortedByIncomingBirthday() -> [Element] {
        sorted {
            // lhs date is today or is in the future
            ($0.date.month, $0.date.day) >= (Date().month, Date().day) ?
                // rhs date is today or is in the future
                ($1.date.month, $1.date.day) >= (Date().month, Date().day) ?
                    // sort them by a month day order
                    ($0.date.month, $0.date.day) < ($1.date.month, $1.date.day) :
                    // otherwise is in increasing order
                    true :
            // lhs date is in the past
            // sort them by a month day order
            ($0.date.month, $0.date.day) < ($1.date.month, $1.date.day)
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
ForEach(birthdays.sortedByIncomingBirthday(), id: \.self) { birthday in
```

Another option is to extend Birthday and add a nextBirthday property this way you can sort it using it as a keyPath for your NSSortDescriptor:

```
extension Date {
    var isInToday: Bool { Calendar.current.isDateInToday(self) }
    var nextBirthday: Date {
        isInToday ? self : Calendar.current.nextDate(after: Date(), matching: Calendar.current.dateComponents([.month, .day, .hour, .minute], from: self), matchingPolicy: .nextTime)!
    }
}
```

---

```
extension Birthday {
    var nextBirthday: Date { date.nextBirthday }
}
```

---

```
NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Birthday.nextBirthday, ascending: true)
```

---

edit/update:

if Birthday date property is optional don't force unwrap its value:

```
extension Birthday {
    var nextBirthday: Date { date?.nextBirthday ?? .distantFuture }
}
```

and the first approach would need to deal with it as well:

```
extension Collection where Element == Birthday {
    func sortedByIncomingBirthday() -> [Element] {
        sorted { lhs, rhs in
            if lhs.date == nil { return false }
            let lhs = lhs.date ?? .distantFuture
            let rhs = rhs.date ?? .distantFuture
            // lhs date is today or is in the future
            return (lhs.month, lhs.day) >= (Date().month, Date().day) ?
                       // rhs date is today or is in the future
                       (rhs.month, rhs.day) >= (Date().month, Date().day) ?
                           // sort them by a month day order
                           (lhs.month, lhs.day) < (rhs.month, rhs.day) :
                           // otherwise is in increasing order
                           true :
                   // lhs date is in the past
                   // sort them by a month day order
                   (lhs.month, lhs.day) < (rhs.month, rhs.day)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Implementing this gives the following error: 
Referencing instance method 'sortedByIncomingBirthday()' on 'Collection' requires the types 'FetchedResults<Birthday>.Element' (aka 'Birthday') and 'Date' be equivalent

at

`ForEach(birthdays.sortedByIncomingBirthday(), id: \.self) { birthday in`

Comment: Yes, it gives the following error at the NSSortDescriptor line:
Thread 1: Fatal error: Could not extract a String from KeyPath Swift.KeyPath<Birthdays.Birthday, Foundation.Date>

Comment: What about the first approach?

Comment: @Shackkill can you please edit your post and show what you have tried?

Comment: @Shackkill don't force unwrap date. Try `var nextBirthday: Date { date?.nextBirthday ?? .distantFuture }`

Comment: With your first solution I made a Birthday with the same day and same year from January to July. All appear in order that they appear in the yearly calendar except when I made July it put itself between February and March
List looks like: JAN 15, FEB 15, JULY 15, MARCH 15, APRIL 15, MAY 15, JUNE 15

Comment: I have tested it here with all sort of dates and it works as expected. Can you please update your post?

Comment: @Shackkill actually if the date was `nil` it was not getting sorted but I have fixed it. Now if the date it is nil it gets to the end of the array

Comment: What should I set for NSSortDescriptor ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have (or going to have) big database, then it would be appropriate to set dedicated attribute in data model (eg. birthMonth: String, having something like "MM/DD") and make CoreData sort engine do sort for you by `Birthday.birthMonth` key path.

Otherwise, in case of small database, you can do additional resort on the fly after data fetched, like in

```
ForEach(birthdays.sorted { $0.month < $1.month }, id: \.self) { birthday in
```

by corresponding `.month` extension implemented as fit for your needs.

Comment: 'something like "Sep, 6"' would sort it alphabetically. what OP needs is "MM/dd". Another thing to be considered is the actual date so that past birthdates (last month or last week) should go to the end

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is this extension of `NSDate` (`NSDate` is crucial because Core Data is widely *NSObject-KVO* based).

It calculates the next occurrence of a date regardless of the year

```
extension NSDate {

    dynamic var nextOccurrence : NSDate {
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let components = calendar.dateComponents([.month, .day], from: self as Date)
        return calendar.nextDate(after: Date(), matching: components, matchingPolicy: .nextTime)! as NSDate
    }
}
```

The corresponding sort descriptor is

```
NSSortDescriptor(key: "date.nextOccurrence", ascending: true)
```

Comment: This wouldn't take the current date into account

Comment: I don't understand.

Comment: OP would like to sort the next birthday. This would sort birthdays that already happened this year before the ones that are still coming. **"to know when the next birthday comes up."**

Comment: It's a bit ambiguous: *I want to sort them in a way that starts with January and Ends with December*

Comment: You would need to change this property to return the number of days from today until  the next birthday

Comment: Maybe using nextDate for components month and day after today

Comment: "I want to sort them in a way that starts with January and Ends with December"
Yeah I worded this badly what I meant was the closest Birthdays appear first, my bad.

Comment: Implementing this gives me the following error:
Thread 1: Exception: "[<__NSTaggedDate 0x8a856bb81bee234f> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key nextOccurrence."       at
`class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {`

Comment: Add `dynamic`, although I'm using the same pattern successfully without `dynamic`.

Comment: The code now runs, but tit seems the dates aren't sorted correctly.
The List now displays the dates in order of when I created them. With the latest appearing highest on the list. Then when rebuilding the code and relaunching the iOS Simulator it displays the last created as the lowest so the reverse of what it did before.
Any idea of whats going on?