# Sorting by month and day with NSSortDescriptor

Tags: ios, swift, sorting, core-data, nssortdescriptor

I am building an app in Swift and I want to display a list with the closest birthdays appearing first on the screen.

e.g. if I have 3 dates (21st of Dec, 21st of May, 21st of Nov) and today is 31st of May. The order shall be 21st of Nov, 21st of Dec and 21st of May.

I am using CoreData and I have an entity called **Entry** having a date:

```
extension Entry {

@nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Entry> {
    return NSFetchRequest<Entry>(entityName: "Entry")
}

@NSManaged public var date: Date?
}
```

And the apparition is made with NSSortDescriptor:

```
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    if let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.persistentContainer.viewContext {
        let request: NSFetchRequest<Entry> = Entry.fetchRequest()
        request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: true)]
        
        if let entriesFromCoreData = try? context.fetch(request) {
            entries = entriesFromCoreData
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried the following, but (1) is giving me a fatal error while extracting a String from KeyPath Swift.KeyPath and (2) is not making the proper sort, taking into consideration the year.

(1)

```
extension Entry {
@nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Entry> {
    return NSFetchRequest<Entry>(entityName: "Entry")
}
@NSManaged public var date: Date?
var nextBirthday: Date { date?.nextBirthday ?? .distantFuture }
}


extension Date {
var isInToday: Bool { Calendar.current.isDateInToday(self) }
var nextBirthday: Date {
    isInToday ? self : Calendar.current.nextDate(after: Date(), matching: Calendar.current.dateComponents([.month, .day, .hour, .minute], from: self), matchingPolicy: .nextTime)!
}}


override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    if let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.persistentContainer.viewContext {
        let request: NSFetchRequest<Entry> = Entry.fetchRequest()
        request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Entry.nextBirthday, ascending: true)]
        
        if let entriesFromCoreData = try? context.fetch(request) {
            entries = entriesFromCoreData
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

(2)

```
extension NSDate {
dynamic var nextOccurrence : NSDate {
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let components = calendar.dateComponents([.month, .day], from: self as Date)
    return calendar.nextDate(after: Date(), matching: components, matchingPolicy: .nextTime)! as NSDate
}}


NSSortDescriptor(key: "date.nextOccurrence", ascending: true)
```

Comment: What is the name of your entity?

Comment: Entry. I have now edited and changed from object to entity. My mistake

Comment: Can you try this?:
request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: #keyPath(Entry.date), ascending: true)]

Comment: It has the same behavior as my implementation from the top: [NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: true)]

Comment: What is wrong with your code without 1 & 2? Does that create an error or not sort correctly?

Comment: You should link the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62415390/2303865) where you got the code from. Btw the answer to your question it is posted there as well `var nextBirthday: Date { date?.nextBirthday ?? .distantFuture }`

Comment: @ChrisTech44: with my initial implementation it sorts the dates ascending or descending but not taking into consideration the present day, so a date from January will always be the first even if we're in 1st of June while a date from 3rd of June, lets say, it shall be the first to show up

Comment: @LeoDabus: You're right, thanks, but that implementation with .distantFuture doesn't solve the problem, at least in my case. My app is crushing with the modification you've mentioned and using request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Entry.nextBirthday, ascending: true)] with the following message:
Foundation/NSObject.swift:124: Fatal error: Could not extract a String from KeyPath Swift.KeyPath<Birthdays.Entry, Foundation.Date>

Do you have any idea why?

Comment: @pAndrei please edit your question and post your actual code. Make sure to provide a [mcve]

Comment: I have edited trial (1) with the relevant code, which makes the app crash